# Python GUI - "<Return>" event only seems to run once

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a Tkinter GUI that will take a value from a textbox and put another value in a second textbox when the user presses Enter. So far I'm stuck on binding the  event correctly. Here is the code:

```
# Event handler functions
def get_input(event):
    print("hello world")
    input_str = tbx_input.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    tbx_output.delete("1.0", "end")
    tbx_output.insert("1.0", input_str)

root = tk.Tk()

# Widget definitions    
tbx_input = tk.Text(
    fg="black",
    bg="white",
    width=40,
    height=1,
)


tbx_output = tk.Text(
    fg="black",
    bg="white",
    width=40,
    height=1,
)

# Event binding
root.bind("<Return>", get_input)

# Display logic
tbx_input.pack()
tbx_output.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here are the steps I take in the GUI.

1. In the first textbox, type something:

[image]

2. Press Enter, and expect the text I typed to appear in the second textbox (As expected)

[image]

3. Then I type something else in the first textbox

[image]

4. And I expect the value to appear in the 2nd textbox. It does not.

[image]

However the terminal output shows that the event function is being triggered, as "hello world" is printed twice:

```
$ python testapp.py
hello world
hello world
```

So while the hello world gets printed once, the "delete" and "insert" calls to the second textbox only happen the first time the function gets called.

Why is this?

Comment: The textboxes are multi-line although they only show one line. You add new lines with text to the input box but only the first line is shown in the output box.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ohhhh. If you're wondering where all that light came from, it's from the lightbulb over my head. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add this here. You think you are putting 2 strings into the input text box, in actual fact you are adding 1 sting `"hello\nhi"` because you set the height to 1 you just cant see the previous input because your `<Return>` bind also moved you to a new line. Also you should only bind the widget you are wanting to bind rather than a global widget like `root` `tbx_input.bind("<Return>", get_input)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the text box from a `Text` widget to an `Entry` widget, and modify the `get` and `insert` calls accordingly. The caveat here is that the `Entry` widget only accepts a single line of text.

```
def get_input(event):
    input_str = tbx_input.get()  # just 'get()' is sufficient here
    tbx_output.delete(0, 'end')  # clear out the output textbox
    tbx_output.insert(0, input_str)  # update the 'insert()' call as well
```

```
tbx_input = tk.Entry(  # use an Entry widget
    fg="black",
    bg="white",
    width=40,
    height=1,
)

tbx_output = tk.Entry(  # use an Entry widget
    fg="black",
    bg="white",
    width=40,
    height=1,
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with your first solution and changed the textboxes to entrys, and now it works fine :)